# Why is this adding more rows than the values (2D Array) set when a cell is edited fast?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, the user ticks a checkbox in a sheet and the script:

1. gets that row's col A data as `testNumber`;
2. looks for it in a separate sheet;
3. modify some of its elements;
4. adds that as a new record to the bottom of the separate sheet.

The problem is when multiple checkboxes are ticked fast, it add the modified arrays correctly, but adds more empty rows to the bottom and I can't find what is causing that in the script below.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  const cellVal = e.range.getValue()
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Search By Name'
    && thisCol === 7
    && thisRow > 5
    && cellVal === true
    && e.range.offset(0, -4).getValue() != '') {

    const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
      lock.waitLock(3000); // wait 03 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 03 seconds.');
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b> Server Busy. Please try after some time <p>");
    }

    const testNumber = e.range.offset(0, -6).getValue();

    const dbSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Database')
    const data = dbSheet.getRange(2, 1, dbSheet.getLastRow(), 12).getValues();

    let filteredperson = data.filter(e => e[11] == testNumber);

    const timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    let maxNumber = Math.max.apply(null, dbSheet.getRange(2, 12, dbSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues());
    maxNumber = maxNumber + 1

    filteredperson[0][0] = timeStamp
    filteredperson[0][11] = maxNumber
    filteredperson[0][12] = ''
    filteredperson[0][13] = ''
    filteredperson[0][14] = ''
    const lastRow = lastRowForColumn(dbSheet, 1);

    dbSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, filteredperson[0].length).setValues(filteredperson);

    e.range.setValue(false);
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Here's the weird behavior, in the last attempt:
[image]

Apreciate your help!

Comment: Where do thisCol, thisRow, cellVal come from?  I don't see them defined anywhere, so not sure how this is even working.

Comment: Sorry, @TheWizEd! Just added these to the top of the script.

Comment: When you say "empty rows" you mean duplicates of filterperson?  Or gaps of emty rows between filterperson(s)?

Comment: @TheWizEd, I mean: When setting the modified array to the sheet (I suppose), it's creating empty rows below the row where the correct value is set. Apparently, if I click fast, it gets the filtered data, but goes on processing as many rows as the times I clicked

Comment: You are not setting an array you are actually only adding one row `dbSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, **1**, filteredperson[0].length).setValues(filteredperson);` so how do you know you are adding empty rows?

Comment: @TheWizEd, I just added a gif, showing the weird behavior. Thanks for not giving up.

Comment: Change your return HTMLService to the way I show an error message in my script.  The way you have it it does nothing.  There may be an error in your lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description

I do not think LockService is doing what you expect for simple trigger onEdit().

I created a simple onEdit() script and tried typing real fast in a spreadsheet.  It works some of the times but then error out without doing what it was supposed to but then resumes.

Also `return HTMLService()` doesn't do anything in Spreadsheet context.

I believe multiple onEdit() can run asynchronously and ignore LockService.

Screen shots

Initial data
[image: Initial data]

Error message
[image: Error message]

Resulting data
[image: Resulting data]

Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
      lock.waitLock(5000);
    }
    catch(err) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
      return;
    }
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.oldValue);
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Reference